# DropdownList in Gridview not saving values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a dropdownlist in one column in editing mode
The problem is that I can't save the selected value after edit and I can show the data from the field when I press edit.
I show some examples doing SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Category") %>' but the SelectedValue is unrecognizable.
The page is

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="Category" >
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I use a textbox instead of the dtopdown then the values after editing are saved correctly
Any ideas?

Comment: where is your code behind?

Comment: There is no code behind. I show a video with the same thing and there wasn't any code there 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hrJQ3D6WTw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem.

In the templatefield I've select edit databindings and then in the SelectedValue I've select Custom Binding and put Bind("category")

Now it works

Comment: Better to place code example, if you found solution